# Custom Time Validation by Data annotation in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

I am trying to implement custom validation in my MVC application. My scenario is

If Closed checkbox is checked, Start and End times are not required.

If Closed checkbox is not checked, I want user to select start and End times from dropdown.

If user select start and end times, I want to validate end time should be greater than start time.

I wrote a custom validation class as below. How can I validate this ?

```
 public class DatesValidation : ValidationAttribute
{
    public bool Closed { get; set; }

    public string Start { get; set; }

    public string End { get; set; }

    public DatesValidation(bool closed, string startTime, string endTime)
    {
        this.Closed = closed;
        this.Start = startTime;
        this.End = endTime;
    }
}
```

Comment: Look at [foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) validation, including the `[RequiredIfFalse]` and `[GreaterThan]` validation attributes.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I look at it. In my case start and end times are not date time, they are string. It is not working if it is string.

Comment: What on earth would you have `DateTime` properties stored as strings?

Comment: @StephenMuecke We are storing start and end time as string in database as 8:00AM - 5:00PM, we are not storing in different columns

Comment: Then you are going to have to write your own validation attributes including your own logic to determine if (say) "4.00PM" is greater than "11.00AM". [This article](http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2) is a good guide to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by Model Validation Attribute. you can use attributes to validate the entire model

**Custom Attribute**

```
public class StartEndDateValidation : ValidationAttribute
{
    public StartEndDateValidation()
    {
        ErrorMessage = "";
    }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        DatesValidation app = value as DatesValidation;
        if (app.Closed)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(app.Start) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(app.End))
            {
                ErrorMessage = "Enter both start and end date";
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
[StartEndDateValidation]
public class DatesValidation
{
    public bool Closed { get; set; }
    public string Start { get; set; }
    public string End { get; set; }
}
```